# How to convert one depth json to several depth by a key in it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, algorithm, frontend

I got a JSON array from server,but it doesn't form right,like

```
 [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "parentId": 1,
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "parentId": 2,
    }
   ]
```

Absolutely,the 2nd item of the array should be a child item to the 1st because of its key "parentId",like

```
 [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "parentId": 1,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "parentId": 2,
            }
        ]
    }
 ]
```

How can I convert the 1st form of JSON to the 2nd?

Comment: This is like converting self-referencing RDMS db table to a hierarchical one. It is not straightforward and algorithms may have performance implications based on data-volume

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution creates a tree and takes a given `parentId` as a root for the tree.

#### How it works:

> Basically, for every object in the array, it takes the `id` for building a new object as well as the `parentId` for the same object.

#### Example:

```
{ "id": 6, "parentId": 4 }
```

generates first with `id`

```
 "6": {
    "id": 6,
    "parentId": 4
}
```

and then this structure with `parentId`:

```
 "4": {
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 6,
            "parentId": 4
        }
    ]
},
```

and while all object treated like this, we eventually get a tree.

If `parentId === root` the root node is found. This is the object for the later return.

```js
var data = [{ "id": 1, "parentId": 0 }, { "id": 6, "parentId": 4 }, { "id": 4, "parentId": 1 }],
    tree = function (data, root) {
        var r, o = {};
        data.forEach(function (a) {
            a.children = o[a.id] && o[a.id].children;
            o[a.id] = a;
            if (a.parentId === root) {
                r = a;
            } else {
                o[a.parentId] = o[a.parentId] || {};
                o[a.parentId].children = o[a.parentId].children || [];
                o[a.parentId].children.push(a);
            }
        });
        return r;
    }(data, 0);
    
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(tree, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: At first I thought I can get a root number from server,now I find i can't.Do you have any idea get it worked without a root number?

Comment: I got it worked,man,I was so stupid not to think about it! I deal with the server developer a root number,thanks a lot man

Comment: usually a value like `undefined` or `null` is used as an indicator for the root. if you like an answer here on stackoverflow, or helped you, you may upvote it and or accept the answer. please have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thanks for your reminding.Your code does work,but when I try to read it I get confused,I can't understand it totally.
Could you add some comment at the code?

Comment: var data = [{
      "id": 1,
      "parentId": 0,
    },{
      "id": 6,
      "parentId": 4,
    },{
      "id": 4,
      "parentId": 1,
    }];
When break the order,it doesn't seem to output rightly

Comment: typing to fast. changed `a.children = r[a.id] && r[a.id].children;` to `a.children = o[a.id] && o[a.id].children;`

Comment: I got it!you have helped me a lot!